# How to toggle dark and white mode in flutter using filters

Tags: flutter, dart, angular-dart

In CSS a dark mode can be toggle using `filter: invert(1) hue-rotate9180deg)`.

Is there a way to achieve that in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is simple trick for dark mode. take a global varible and use it anywhere to change the app theme to dark to light or light to dark. Add this to your MaterialApp.
Here is a example:

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ProjectResource.darkTheme? ThemeData.dark():ThemeData.light(),
      
     home: Homepage(title: 'Homepage',notifyParent: refresh,),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have this already implemented. What I want to know is if there is a way of getting a light theme from the existing app colour using filters. For example, let assume an app is implemented in dark mode(dark theme) with a dark blue shade, is there a way of getting a light theme base on the existing colour. say light blue shade.